# import java.util.Calendar not working

Tags: java, android

```
import java.util.Calendar;
.....


..... 
calender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Process to get Current Date
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                // Launch Date Picker Dialog
                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                /**Some thing to do here**/


                            }
                        }, year, mMonth, mDay);
                dpd.show();
            }
        });
......
```

this code is used to display a dialog to select date.

But while trying import calender class Android studio displays error!

[error on Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJKOq.png).

Android Studio says cannot resolve symbol Calendar.

Does anyone knows any solution or has experienced the same problem ??

> I'm using Android Studio 1.2.1.1

Comment: Can you try File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...?

Comment: @M D that quo and my quo are completely different ... His code gets compiled and get NULL POINT .... I am not being able to compile my code

Comment: He says later in that post, that he can't compile the code after sometime

Comment: @Airudh that also still do not solve my problem

Comment: why I am not being able to import Calendar ?